# Restler API Explorer array parameter in GET request

Tags: php, rest, restler

[image: Restler Explorer]

Is it possible to make a call from the explorer to an GET API that has an array parameter? As you can see in the picture above, the explorer generates the URL by encoding the comma instead of treating it as an array separator. Is there a way to make it accept an array?

Here's my parameter definition in the code.

```
@param array $ids array of user ID's {@type int} {@from query}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct way of passing array as a query string is to use `[]` and repeat the name. For example

```
users.json?ids[]=1&ids[]=2
```

Unfortunately Explorer does not support it yet!

We use to support string to array conversion by splitting out of the box in earlier versions of Restler but then taken out to support the above method instead

We just brought it back in the latest v3 branch (just pushed) which will soon be part of RC5 release

In order to make use of it, you need to add `{@fix}` or `{@fix true}` to the parameter comment

Comment: Got it, looks like I'll just wait for the RC5 release then :)

Comment: I think it is stable enough, just use it!